# can't install XDEBUG on windows?

Tags: php, windows, xdebug

my php version is PHP Version `5.3.6`.

Xdebug setting in php.ini:

```
[Xdebug]

 zend_extension_ts="D:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1

;IP
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace = On
xdebug.show_exception_trace = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.collect_vars = On
xdebug.collect_return = On
xdebug.collect_params = On
```

i have installed PHP 5.3 VC6 (32 bit)/ PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit). they are both failed.

when typed "php --ini" on cmd . it shows:
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in order to find the correct binary to use, please follow the instructions at http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

cheers,
Derick

Comment: Well.. This is funny... I need php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.4-vc9.dll but that doesn't even exist >_>

Comment: People, don't be discouraged by the fact that the link is outdated and redirected elsewhere. The target page will still help you to pick the right version.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to mix 'n match modules, try a stock download from Apache Friends. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

XAMPP comes with xdebug right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to download the correct version of xdebug for your version of Windows / PHP.  There are VC9 builds [here](http://xdebug.org/download.php), just select the appropriate one for 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't know which  version of xdebug i should installed? my php version is 5.3.6. the operating system is XP.

Comment: @enjoylife it's going to be one of the PHP 5.3 VC9 builds on that page from my answer.  You'll need to grab the appropriate one for 32-bit vs 64-bit (info on that here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions).  It will be one of **PHP 5.3 VC9 (64 bit)** or **PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit)**  You can get the _ts_ variant if you want, but typically PHP is run in a non-threaded mode.

Answer (score 0):

[http://nepuzz.com/index/detail/18][1]

You can check the above link and install xdebugger in sublime 3 with wamp server easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Xamp.

1. Download windows binary corresponding your php version: https://xdebug.org/download
2. (optional) move downloaded file (php_xdebug.......dll in common location and rename it: for example `xdebug.dll` in `C:\phpextensions\`
3. Run `php --ini` in cmd to know where is the php.ini file (p.ex: C:\php\php.ini)
4. Edit C:\phpextensions\xdebug.dll and add following line:

```
zend_extension = C:\globally\debug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
```