# Can't install Xdebug on php 5.4.4

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I tried to install the xdebug on my `xampp` running `php 5.4.4`, after spending hours, I still couldn't manage to install it!

Here is my settings in php.ini

```
zend_extension = "Z:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="Z:\xampp\tmp"
```

Could anyone spot any mistake?

Thanks

Comment: What si the actual problem? Any error message?

Comment: The xdebug binary must be compatible with your PHP binary (same compiler, same bitness). Check your apache error logs for messages when the server is started.

Comment: @arkascha when using Netsbean to debug, the error message is: xbebug is not installed or not configured properly

Comment: @jon I already use phpinfo() function to check version of php before download xdebug

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show xdebug? If not then you should have some error inside the error log when restarting the http server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't install XDEBUG on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675172/cant-install-xdebug-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the Wizard at http://xdebug.org/wizard.php - it will tell you which settings to make exactly, and which binary to download.

Comment: This site is really great, however, it still doesn't work for me :((.
What I'm wondering is should I put those values like: "localhost", "Z:\xampp\tmp" etc in the double quotes or not!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, couldn't run xdebug with xampp and using IDE netbeans, what i've done:
-downloaded the version indicated for my php version VC9 TS! (it needs to be TS)
-edited the lines in the php.ini to this:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

and that was it, hope it helps.
cheers