# xdebug 2.2.1 and php 5.4.4

Tags: php, zend-framework, build, mamp, xdebug

I am trying to install Xdebug 2.2.1 on my mac. I have MAMP installed and it runs PHP 5.4.4. The problem I am having is that I cannot compile the source code. I have tried some suggestions, such as

[Failing to build xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132319/failing-to-build-xdebug)

but the solution it gives is not the right one, because it uses the Xcode php platform (5.3.x version) in order to build Xdebug. 
I also have tried

[Can't install Xdebug on php 5.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323040/cant-install-xdebug-on-php-5-4-4)

but the php sdk does not let me build Xdebug, it throws some errors I cannot manage.

Does anybody succeeded in building Xdebug for PHP 5.4.4?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the Liip PHP package.  It's pretty straightforward to install and includes the XDebug extension.

http://php-osx.liip.ch/