# XAMPP can not install xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

Hello I have installed xampp, changed the php.ini to this:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

So I created a php file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Copy pasted the content and pasted in the xdebug wizard and got this output:

```
Tailored Installation Instructions

Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.7
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
Instructions

Download
Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\
Restart the webserver
If you like Xdebug, and thinks it saves you time and money, please have a look at the donation page.
```

This tells me that it is not installed, so I followed the instructions and restarted the server. Opened the info php again, copied everything again and pasted it in the wizard again. Press the button and I get the exact same output, I don't know what I am doing wrong can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: The wizard seems broken, can you follow the instructions at http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=950#c2501 to provide me with some more info to fix this?

Comment: @Derick Your link asks you to sign up for an account. Anonymous login is broken and the capta widget is broken so you can't create a new account.

Comment: The captha was indeed broken - I've fixed that now.

Comment: Later discussion with a configuration that worked for me on Win 7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466062/cant-install-xdebug-on-xampp-and-windows-xp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't install XDEBUG on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675172/cant-install-xdebug-on-windows)

Comment: here is a step by step tutorial please take a look
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 19):

**Step 1:**  goto https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

**step 2:** copy and paste your phpinfo output to textarea which will be displayed on https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

**step 3:** click on analyze my phpinfo() output button, it will analyze your system and based on that it will give you suitable **php_xdebug.dll** file that you need to put at **D:\xampp\php\ext** folder

**step 4:** edit your **php.ini** file and add following line 
**zend_extension = D:\xampp\php\ext\your-php_xdebug.dll**

**step 5:** Restart Server

Reference Video Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbJOP0YcSjs

complete video Tutorial for PHP Debug Example : [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a14kN2u5nEk)

Comment: Using the wizard helped me get the xdebug going for my installation.

Answer (score 14):

**Recent** XAMPP version(mine is v3.2.2) already had the file **php_xdebug.dll** in `xampp\php\ext` folder , so we **don't need** go to https://xdebug.org/wizard.php for downloading the file.

Just open the file `xampp\php\php.ini`, add the codes:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

Restart the XAMPP, then you could see the xdebug is working by type `php --version` in CMD:

[image: Xdebug]

Answer (score 1):

Have you rectified the issue ?, if not please try this. I am having the same situations as yours, and I got result by

1)php.ini file content

```
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host="localhost:81"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

please place the above mentioned dll at c:\xampp\php\ext\

xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.5 - This is the IPv4 address of my system, I changed to this because I couldn't debug with localhost and 127.0.0.1.

in NetBeans IDE, open Tools-> Options->PHP->Debugging. The values of debugger port and Session Id should match with the port and idekey specified in php.ini

Now save php.ini, restart Apache and now try for debugging

Thanks Johnson

Comment: I use xampp (php 7.0)
I found tailored installation usefull
https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

I had pasted `zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14.dll` and after apache restart works!

Comment: here explains step by step procedure
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved checking the versions of php and xampp: it turned out, xampp was 32 bits (installed in a 64 bits computer) and I chose the wrong version of xdebug (it has to be 32 bits).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, make sure your xampp installation doesn't already have php_xdebug file in the php/ext folder before downloading xdebug dll. If the xampp/php/ext folder already has a php_xdebug file, just add 1 line in the php.ini file

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

Comment: This just repeats information already found in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

In general this extension come with the XAMPP package (look into your \xampp\php\ext folder) but it's not added to your php.ini automatically.

add this line manually into your php.ini

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

It's all ;) that worked for me

Comment: Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension.