# Can't install Xdebug on XAMPP and Windows XP

Tags: php, windows, xampp, xdebug

I know, this has been asked several times, but the answers did not solve my problem.

I am running XAMPP 1.8.2 on Windows XP SP3 and am struggling in installing XDebug.

I downloaded XDebug from the website. Unfortunately, the installation wizard did not work for me, my PHP Version is 5.4.16, so I chose the file for `PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit)`.

I configured my php.ini according to different tutorials:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "D:\Stefan\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

When restarting apache, no additional entries show up in the `phpinfo()`. I have checked, that no other debugging or accelleration modules are activated, and also tried to change the Xdebug port, but nothing worked.

The Apache and Windows Error Logs do not contain any entries related to this issue.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you have the thread safe version of PHP installed?

Comment: Yes. My `php.ini` says: `Thread Safety  enabled `

Comment: Why did you download XDebug? XAMPP should come with it's own dll

Comment: Are there any other Zend extensions loaded?

Comment: The dll, that came with XAMPP didn't work (same issue), so I tried to download it manually. There aren't any other zend_extensions loaded.

Comment: Are you sure zend optimizer is not enabled?

Comment: yes. here is my full php.ini: http://pastebin.com/rPM7qVF8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the XDebug.dll that comes with XAMMP.

Download the [TS](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll) version from the xdebug website

And configure like this

```
zend_extension = "D:\Stefan\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\Stefan\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\Stefan\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: When I use the zend_extension without "ts", I get the following error when starting apache: http://imgur.com/1dOKL4H

Comment: In english, it says something like "The procedure entry point "zend_unmangle_property_name_ex" cannot be found in dynamic link library php5ts.dll"

Comment: Try the XDebug ddl that came with XAMPP and use zend_extension.

Comment: Updated my answer.. that should fix the issue!

Comment: This is the right answer. There is a bug in the xdebug that comes with xampp. Just grab the latest version from http://xdebug.org/download.php

Comment: The version you specified, php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll, is the only one that works. I tried the other variants (vc9 and vc11, standard and x86_64) and they either gave errors when starting Apache, or, showed a "failed to load" message in NetBeans when I tried to debug (and it would not stop at breakpoints). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

***Ok same problem here but i resolved problem***

[Download it HERE , if you want BUT](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll)

Xampp 1.8.2 no need Xdebug more because , Xampp 1.8.2 have Xdebug.dll !!!

**look like this :**

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

So sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem about confusion which php.ini is used, look which php.ini apache uses. You might be editing the wrong ini file.

Look for **Loaded Configuration File** in `phpinfo()`

[image]

Sometimes it loads from

`..\bin\apache\Apache#.#.#\bin\php.ini`

In stead of

`...\bin\php\php#.#.#\php.ini`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this potential issue and have triple-checked it. I am definitely editing the correct ini-file (and no additional files)

Answer (score 0):

Check security options of **.dll** xdebug file. If you see on file's icon small lock icon - nobody except you can't use this file. In that case add Users group in security tab in file's properties.