# How to use Xdebug with XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

At work, we use dockers to run our servers, and we work with PhpStorm and Xdebug. I want to use Xdebug at home using XAMPP, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Usually, at work, when I want to debug stuff, I add `xdebug_break();` somewhere near the offending code line, turn on "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections", and then it would stop at that point, waiting for me to manually continue. I want it to work like that at home, too.

What I did so far:

- I installed Xdebug and checked `phpinfo();` to make sure it's actually installed properly:
  [image]
- I updated php.ini and restarted the server:
  [image]
- I made sure the debug port is set to 9000, which is the default (hence why I didn't include it in the php.ini file)

Now, nothing happens when I go to the page with the `xdebug_break();`. What do I need to do to make it work?

[image]

Comment: 1) Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 2) If Xdebug is installed, provide Xdebug section of phpinfo() output + enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677792/7644018) helped me get Xdebug working with my Xampp setup.