# Installing xdebug using "pecl install xdebug" on xampp

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, pecl, php-5.5

When I tried to install Xdebug using

> pecl install xdebug

I'm getting the following error. I'm using the latest xampp bitnami distribution on Windows 7 machine.

> downloading xdebug-2.2.5.tgz ... Starting to download xdebug-2.2.5.tgz
>   (255,840 bytes)
>   .....................................................done: 255,840
>   bytes 66 source files, building WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\php.exe
>   appears to have a suffix \php.exe, but config variable php_suffix
>   does not match ERROR: The DSP xdebug.dsp does not exist.

Do I need to configure anything on php.ini for this?

Comment: Actually in xampp bitnami distribution, the xdebug DLL is already included. Only thing to do is configure the php.ini. The above is only for 'nix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't install XDEBUG on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675172/cant-install-xdebug-on-windows)