# How to configure PHP XDebug with Eclipse on XAMPP v3.2.1 for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, xdebug

XDebug is not enabled by default in XAMPP on Windows, and all attempts to install a debugger lead to dead trails.

`pecl install xdebug` does not work on windows, and errors out with `ERROR: The DSP xdebug.dsp does not exist.`

The only download of Zend Debugger is a cygwin build, not XAMPP compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't install XDEBUG on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675172/cant-install-xdebug-on-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DLL `php_xdebug.dll` already comes bundled with XAMPP but for some silly reason the config is commented out by default.

Uncomment the lines near the end of `php.ini`, set `remote_enable=1`  and restart Apache:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\usr\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\usr\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\usr\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: These lines do not exist at all in my php.ini or even in the php.ini-development with XAMPP version 3.2.2. Adding these lines to the end of php.ini and restarting Apache did work for me.